# redshift COPY TO file from Xen-tables not supported

Tags: copy, amazon-redshift

I am trying to copy (not unload) a table from redshift to a local file.
I run in psql:

```
\copy my_schema.my_table to 'my_file.csv' with csv;
```

I get the error

```
ERROR:  COPY TO file from Xen-tables not supported
```

Running

```
\copy (select * from my_schema.my_table) to 'my_file.csv' with csv;
```

raises syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
```

How should I perform the copy?
Thanks,
Dafna

Answer (score 7):

You can redirect the psql output to a local file:

```
psql [your connection options go here] -F, -A \
  -c 'select * from my_schema.my_table' >my_file.csv
```

`-F,` sets the field separator to a comma

`-A` gives you unaligned/unformatted output

To specify a different delimiter like pipe, use `'|'` instead of the `-F`.

Note: The above command won't tolerate newlines in text fields, they are not encoded and terminate the line prematurely.

Comment: Thank you, but when I use -F, the output separates values that have the comma character in them. How should I avoid that?

Comment: You're correct -- see the update, that solution should work for you (otherwise, you can also consider using a different separator instead of a comma or to manually escape your fields with quotes).

Comment: Actually, COPY TO STDOUT also seems to be missing from Redshift (reverted my edit). Try the manual escaping route or use another delimiter.